# Disabling an input when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I need to disable a cmp when a checkbox is checked, I tried this:

```html
<script language="text/javascript">

var x = document.getElementById("SemPretencao").checked;

function desativar() {

 if (x==true) {
  alert("Seu Babacaum");
  document.getElementById("salario").disabled=true;
 } else {
  alert("Babaquara");
  document.getElementById("salario").disabled=false;
 }

}

document.getElementById("SemPretencao").addEventListener("click", desativar();, false);

</script>

inputs:

    <a class="field_names">Pretenção Salarial: </a> <input type="number" class="number_inputs" name="salario" id="salario"> <br>
 <a class="field_names">Não Tenho Pretenção Salarial </a> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_input" name="SemPretencao" id="SemPretencao">
```

Sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian.

Comment: You'll have to check if the checkbox is checked *inside* the function, otherwise the value never changes.

Comment: And, the script has to come after the elements in the DOM; or you'll need a DOM ready handler.

Comment: Also, `desativar();,`  is a syntax error. It should be `desativar,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addEventListener` is wrong. You're calling the function instead of passing it. Your function can also be simplified a bit. Try this:

```
function desativar() {
  document.getElementById("salario").disabled = document.getElementById("SemPretencao").checked;
}

document.getElementById("SemPretencao").addEventListener("click", desativar, false);
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/0ffbp838/)

Comment: As `this` refers to the changed element, the `document.getElementById("SemPretencao").checked` part can be replaced with `this.checked;`

Answer (score 0):

I found some issues in your code. The x definition should have been inside the function. The eventListener was messing, it should have listen for the change event. I put this listener inside the HTML element (subject to debate, but working).

```js
function desativar() {
var x = document.getElementById("SemPretencao").checked;
 if (x==true) {
     alert("Seu Babacaum");
  document.getElementById("salario").disabled=true;
 } else {
  alert("Babaquara");
  document.getElementById("salario").disabled=false;
 }

}
```

```html
    <a class="field_names">Pretenção Salarial: </a> <input type="number" class="number_inputs" name="salario" id="salario"> <br>
 <a class="field_names">Não Tenho Pretenção Salarial </a> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_input" name="SemPretencao" id="SemPretencao" onchange="desativar()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your "click" event to change, remove the parentheses after `desativar`, and move the `x` variable inside the function :

```
function desativar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("SemPretencao").checked;
    if (x==true) {
        alert("Seu Babacaum");
        document.getElementById("salario").disabled=true;
    } else {
        alert("Babaquara");
        document.getElementById("salario").disabled=false;
    }

}

document.getElementById("SemPretencao")
 .addEventListener("change", desativar, false);
```